# Where should non MS command line tools be placed in Windows?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, cmd.exe

I recently needed some of the really useful nirsoft tools.  Many are command line tools and they need a location in the path to run from.  I dumped them somewhere to get things done but I want to know if there is an official place in the file system for these tools.

I do not think they should be directly in "Program Files" nor do I like the proliferation of application specific locations because they bloat the path environment variable.  Its hard enough to read as it is.

I am considering a top level "bin" directory or "tools" but I fear it might offend some MS rule.

suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a need for a special place for 3rd party tools. I always run them from a shortcut on the desktop or toolbar.

Comment: Both Ben N and PycoGeek seem to like the idea of a c:\tools directory with some variations. I will try that ans see how it goes.

Comment: `C:\tools` is used by [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) (I currently have C:\tools\python and C:\tools\msys64 from chocolatey). Although not all packages are installed there, e.g. its nircmd is in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin

Comment: I made a "Cltools" directory for mine. Works quite fine.

Answer (score 10):

There is no official place for third-party programs. Your file system is yours to use as you please, but I would recommend against putting them in OS-critical places like `\Windows` or `\Windows\System32`.

My recommendation is to create a subfolder of your user profile, say `\Users\Ben\Tools`, and put your stuff there. Then, type "edit environment" in your Start box or Start screen, and select *Edit environment variables for your account*. (On Windows XP, this is in the Advanced part of System Properties.)

[image: environment variables editor]

If the top box (per-user variables) contains `PATH`, press Edit. Append a semicolon and then the full path to your tools folder. If you don't already have `PATH`, press New, and fill it out appropriately.

[image: adding the PATH variable]

If you want this change to apply to all users, place the tools folder in a publicly accessible location (`\Tools` works) and update the `PATH` variable in the "System variables" list rather than the per-user one.

You may need to log off and back on before that folder will effectively be ubiquitous.

Comment: This makes the tools available to only the one logged in user.  I teach at a school where people can roam from machine to machine but might expect consistent commands available and consistent locations.

Comment: @ProsaicHacker In that case, place the files in a publicly accessible location (`\Tools` works) and update the system `PATH` instead of the per-user one.

Answer (score 1):

This is your own computer?  so some rule has what value?  You already understand the path and the messes already there with the pigpiles and path additions,  how could any of that be worse than what you think up to organise it :-)

I tend to put small utilities and commands in folders I designated for such things and actually not far down from the root of C because it is likely I will be using them in batches where the full path for the item is used every time, with no changes or dependancy on the path variables.  With no dependancy on about anything.  I also will have made icons and use a 3rd party toolbars to access the stuff quickly.

Half the point of good tight small programs is they can be backed-up (as files)  without cross links and registry entries , they do not toss more path noise in, and operate without tons of dependencies.  They run fast because they are small and tight, they run out of anywhere.  Many of Utilities of the small non-dependant type are useful for diagnosing problems with the computer, no mater what is wrong, so I feel quick access to them is very important, because of that I avoid putting this grouping of programs where if things go badly they are not accessable.

The scripts/batches used for them could easily be stored in the same locations , and then CD (current directory) in the batches would work out of those locations (note, I said I use full paths).  Running a CMD (context menu) out of the current directory another method to avoid paths.   Determine the ammount of these utils, set up an organisation that you can live with, back-up (simply) that grouping and stuff the rules :-)

MS has not completely taken away our ability to have stuff simple and fast Yet!

I have used folders names of Tools, Utils, Desk, Diag (for diagnostics) in the root forever for the tiny utils, many of those are subfoldered to keep a programs parts and pieces all contained. It has not failed yet.